# Textarea and dropdown collective management

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Hy!

Here's a Plunker DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/gBFRpL1zOfMtKcQBA0j1?p=preview

I want the `dropdown` to show if `textarea` has the focus. If it's blurred, the dropdown should hide.

But if I click on the dropdown, the textarea loses focus. The textarea should not lose focus, when the dropdown is clicked.

Any ideas?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is, that of course if you click on the dropdown, the dropdown has the focus! And if the dropdown has the focus, the textarea loses its focus. Do you understand the problem?

Try to change your logic.

- textarea: **focus**, dropdown: blur,  dropdown: **show**
- textarea: blur,  dropdown: **focus**, dropdown: **show**
- textarea: blur,  dropdown: blur,  dropdown: hide

only one element can have the focus!

Comment: Hey, did this work for you? Do you have any more problems with this? If it works it would be great to mark the answer as correct .Thanks :)